# Redis doesn't automatically start after reboot in systemd even if it's enabled

Tags: 16.04, systemd, autostart, redis

I want to enable automatic start of redis database with systemd after boot. I got weird issues with x86 Ubuntu on ec2:

systemd claims that service is enabled.

```
ubuntu@:~$ systemctl status redis
● redis.service - Redis In-Memory Data Store
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/redis.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

The symlink also exists:

```
root@ip-172-31-23-10:~# ls -l /etc/systemd/system/multi.target.wants/redis.service
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 33 Nov  5 10:25 /etc/systemd/system/multi.target.wants/redis.service -> /etc/systemd/system/redis.service
```

```
cat /etc/systemd/system/redis.service

[Unit]
Description=Redis In-Memory Data Store
After=network.target

[Service]
Use=redis
Group=redis
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/redis-cli shutdown
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi.target
```

After rebooting of the machine I see that the service is not started (systemctl status redis) and there're no logs of attempts to start the service:

```
sudo journalctl -u redis
-- No entries --
```

If I start redis manually - everything works ok

```
root@:~# systemctl start redis
root@:~# systemctl status redis
● redis.service - Redis In-Memory Data Store
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/redis.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2020-11-05 10:29:57 UTC; 4s ago
 Main PID: 2107 (redis-server)
    Tasks: 5
   Memory: 2.9M
      CPU: 13ms
   CGroup: /system.slice/redis.service
           └─2107 /usr/local/bin/redis-server 127.0.0.1:6379

Nov 05 10:29:57 ip- redis-server[2107]: 2107:M 05 Nov 2020 10:29:57.126 # WARNING: The TCP backlog setting of 511
Nov 05 10:29:57 ip- redis-server[2107]: 2107:M 05 Nov 2020 10:29:57.126 # Server initialized
Nov 05 10:29:57 ip- redis-server[2107]: 2107:M 05 Nov 2020 10:29:57.126 # WARNING overcommit_memory is set to 0! B
Nov 05 10:29:57 ip- redis-server[2107]: 2107:M 05 Nov 2020 10:29:57.131 * Loading RDB produced by version 6.0.8
Nov 05 10:29:57 ip redis-server[2107]: 2107:M 05 Nov 2020 10:29:57.131 * RDB age 717 seconds
Nov 05 10:29:57 ip redis-server[2107]: 2107:M 05 Nov 2020 10:29:57.131 * RDB memory usage when created 0.86 Mb
Nov 05 10:29:57 ip redis-server[2107]: 2107:M 05 Nov 2020 10:29:57.133 * DB loaded from disk: 0.006 seconds
Nov 05 10:29:57 ip redis-server[2107]: 2107:M 05 Nov 2020 10:29:57.133 * Ready to accept connections
Nov 05 10:29:57 ip redis-server[2107]: 2107:M 05 Nov 2020 10:29:57.133 # systemd supervision requested, but NOTIF
Nov 05 10:29:57 ip redis-server[2107]: 2107:M 05 Nov 2020 10:29:57.133 # systemd supervision requested, but NOTIF
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this EXACT same problem.  I tried numerous things including doing:

```
systemctl enable redis.service
```

Yes, I know it was already enabled but it was not autostarting.  I got an error that systemctl cannot enable linked services.  This was because the file `/etc/systemd/system/redis.service` was actually a symlink to `/lib/systemd/system/redis-server.service`

I finally found the answer, you have to run enable/disable commands against the real location of the file, IE:

```
systemctl enable /lib/systemd/system/redis-server.service
```

Once I did that, I rebooted and viola, Redis was running.